# Simple UPDATE suddenly takes up to 2 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am running a website with about 35k users in a table `users`. Everytime a user requests a page, the database row for that user is updated with the current timestamp. This query, a simple

```
UPDATE `users` SET `last_seen`=1619472395 WHERE `id`=12345678
```

usually took like a microsecond or so.

From one day to the next, this query now takes much longer, sometimes up to two seconds, making the website very slow. Strange thing: Sometimes the query is as fast as you would expect, one second later it takes two seconds.

The user table is tiny, only has 35k rows (MyISAM), ´id´ is the primary key and the total database size is not even 100 MByte.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: Did you create index in there?

Comment: @FarrukhFaizy The question says it's the primary key.

Comment: The only guess I have is that something else is locking the table and it's waiting for the lock. If you can switch to InnoDB it uses row-level locking, so this should be less of a problem.

Comment: do always use innodb, unless you have clear evidence you would do better with myisam

Comment: Can I just switch to INNO like that???

Comment: `ALTER TABLE users ENGINE=InnoDB;` this should not take long on such a small table.

Comment: You might like to read [my answer to MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706717/20860)

Comment: I changed to InnoDB and we are back to normal speed. Still, this does not explain the extremely bad speed on a rather tiny table. 35k rows should be nothing.